# Forwarding the results of text processing commands to certain locations in an .ods file

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, ods

I am looking for an efficient way to import the data from a bunch of text files into an .ods file. I have no problem in processing the text files with commands like grep and sed, however, I do not know if it is possible to redirect the results of these commands into a certain location in an ods file.

Answer (score 1):

The [.ods file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification) is basically an xml file format.  In the case of .fods it is straight xml.  In the case of .ods it is zipped xml.  So directly inserting content from text files will likely require some xml tools.  I'm using Ubuntu and found [xml2/2xml](http://dan.egnor.name/xml2/ref) could be useful for converting between xml and xml-path-style text. (`sudo apt-get install xml2`)

So you will have to do the following:

1. `unzip` the .ods file - the cell data will be in a file called content.xml
2. `xml2 < content.xml` to get raw text out of the xml
3. Edit the raw text with your content
4. Convert the edited raw text back to xml using `2xml`
5. Rezip up the previously unzipped .ods, including your edited content

This may be quite an involved/cumbersome process.  Alternatively I'd suggest simply saving your .ods file as a .csv file instead and directly editing the comma-separated-values.